# My company has hired someone I had history with, what to do?

Tags: united-kingdom

I've found out that my company has hired someone who I won't be able to work with - think emotional abuse rather than fisticuffs.

We wouldn't be working together, but would have to collaborate on various projects. I'm not prepared to do this. It's a mid-size organization with little opportunity for me to shift position.

I'm not a business critical superstar, but my position would be hard to very hard to replace. This would also be true for the new hire.

I'm going to be actively looking for a new position, but what should I do in the short-term?
Should I raise my concerns with my line manager (board level director) now or wait until I've secured a new position?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I voted to close the question, because the question is about a personal choice. Since there is no intention to amend things to make them better, there is nothing we can do to help, unfortunately.

Comment: Was the original problematic behavior documented? Is there a police report or a report to HR of your old company if it was at the workplace?

Comment: @Job_September_2020 while some of your edits in this post are helpful, -ise vs -ize is a UK vs US spelling difference. It was not wrong before. You should not change such things. They are not mistakes; some words are just spelled differently in different countries.

Comment: What is the nature of that history? Does that history make you look bad? If it doesn't, you should definitely share what happened with your current manager.

Answer (score 7):

Talk to your manager about it. It is in his best interest to keep you working at your best. If this new colleague really makes you that nervous, it should be his top priority to protect you. Of course it may not be possible to prevent all contact.

In parallel, I would recommend you to work on your sensibility towards that colleague. If something traumatic happened, get some counselling, or at least talk to close friends about your problems with that person.

Comment: If there was a situation that was criminal, and at a previous company you would have contacted the police if that person hadn't left voluntarily the company, then ask a lawyer

Answer (score 2):

How long ago were you working together? If it was several years ago, I'd wait and see whether the new hire in the meantime has matured and become a more responsible professional.

Furthermore, don't give this person the power to affect your work life and mental health. Don't allow your fears and anxiety take control over you. Nothing has happened yet; remember you are in a stronger position than the new employee, they are on a probationary period. Your job is secure, theirs isn't yet.

If the hire returns to their abusive behaviour make sure to keep a record of what was said and have a word with your manager the very next day. Tell them you wanted to give the new hire a second chance but they blew it.

Comment: The question does not say, if the original problematic situation was at work. Might be a private situation.

Comment: @nvoigt fair observation, I presumed if the new hire was a former partner or relative the OP would have said.

Comment: Either way, some people do grow up. There’s a chance that you run into this person and get an apology for what happened before. Alcoholic going dry can make a huge difference for example. Separating from a toxic partner. Or they might come back worse than ever. Anything can happen.

Answer (score 0):

> We wouldn't be working together, but would have to collaborate on various projects. I'm not prepared to do this

If your're not going to work with this person and you're prepared to follow through on that then yes you need to communicate this to your manager. The more advance notice they have the more potential options they have to avoid the situation.

If you don't want to disclose the details then just say you won't work with them and leave it at that. Something like:

> "[Person] and I have a history. I don't want to disclose the details but I cannot and will not work or interact with them under any circumstances."

And then see how your boss responds and go from there. If they press you for details then just repeat it and make it clear that this is a red line for you that isn't going to change.